# Flying back to Europe from India with passport that does not have 6 months till expiry date for EU citizen

Tags: air-travel, schengen, passports, passport-renewals, lithuanian-citizens

We are holders of Lithuanian (EU) passports. I got visas to India for a year that will end next November 14th, passport of my two-year-old son will end on 10th of November since passports for babies expire every 2 years...

Would we be allowed to board a plane that lands anywhere in Schengen area on 8th of November next year or only one that lands in Lithuania (leaving two days of passport validity for my son)?

Comment: Many countries require a minimum passport validity for **visitors** to they can make leave again if the departure is delayed (e.g. by a medical emergency or cancelled flights). That is not an issue for EU citizens in the EU because they do not have to leave.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can land anywhere in the EU or the Schengen area with a valid passport.  There is no need for the passport to be valid beyond the end of your stay.

This is specified in directive [2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616), article 5:

> Member States shall grant Union citizens leave to enter their territory with a valid identity card or passport

I can also speak from firsthand experience traveling around the Schengen area last August with an EU citizen whose passport expired in September.

Article 6 allows countries to require you to have a valid passport or national ID card for the duration of your stay, but the details vary from one country to the next.  In practice, it's unlikely to be a huge problem if your son's passport expires while you're in another EU country, but it might be simpler to renew it before you travel.